# Connecting Two Datasets in Chart.js Into a Single Line

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have two separate datasets in Chart.JS, one represents a selection of historical data, the other the predictions based on that data. Here is what the chart currently looks like. Historical data is black, prediction is blue:

[image: Historical data is in black, prediction data is in blue]

I'd like to maintain the two as separate datasets, but connect them so the chart displays as a single line. In a previous version I accomplished this by adding a datapoint to the prediction dataset that is an exact duplicate of the final datapoint in the historical set, but this creates an inaccurate redundancy I want to avoid.

Unless there's some chart.js setting I've been unable to find I'm worried I might have to register a plugin to do this, which seems like it would become needlessly clunk. Thanks.

Comment: the dataset in Chart.js is just an array of values. If you have your sets of data in separate arrays and combine them only for populating the chart, it should work as you desire. I guess it also depends on which data structure you are using.

Comment: That's a good idea, the issue then is that in that case I'm not sure how the change the color of the second dataset line to make it very clear which value is historical versus a prediction.

Comment: I suggest you look at the multi-axis example on the site. It may help. http://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/charts/line/multi-axis.html   I believe it has something to do with the backgroundColor property of each dataset in the chart.

Comment: Yeah I understand how to assign different colors to each dataset, the issue is that if I combine the datasets in order to have one continuous line then I'll have to pick one color that defines the entire dataset. I'm currently exploring whether I could find the index of the last historical point and somehow change the line color for every point on the line that comes after that.

Comment: I don't think Chart.js has it built in to support different point colors. They have a point style that changes the symbol used for each point. You can change the size of the symbol for the different datasets. The interpolation example might be a compromise for you.

Answer (score 1):

Managed to solve the problem, posting to help anyone with a similar problem.

I ended up creating a chart.js plugin that draws a line finds the X and Y coordinates of the last historical point and then draws a line between that and the X and Y coordinate of the first prediction point. After beating my head against it for a while I can't believe it was so simple.

I'm posting the code down below - this is a react application so it may not fit cleanly into every use case. The JSFiddle isn't setup to work, but you can see how to grab the point data which was the hardest part for me!

```js
//Grab the chart meta data and identify the x and y coordinates of the 
appropriate points
    var meta = chartInstance.getDatasetMeta(0);
    var predictionMeta = chartInstance.getDatasetMeta(1);
    var chartFirstPointX = meta.data[this.props.actualData.length - 1]._model.x;
    var lastActualY = meta.data[this.props.actualData.length - 1]._model.y;
    
    var predictionFirstPointX = predictionMeta.data[0]._model.x;
    var predictionFirstPointY = predictionMeta.data[0]._model.y;



    Chart.pluginService.register({
      id: 'forecastLine',
      beforeDraw: function(chartInstance) {
        var ctx = chartInstance.chart.ctx,
            yTop = chartInstance.chartArea.top,
            yBottom = chartInstance.chartArea.bottom,
            firstPredictionX = predictionFirstPointX,
            firstPredictionY = chartInstance.config.data.datasets[1].data[0].y;

        ctx.fillStyle = '#FAFAFA';
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, chartInstance.chart.width, chartInstance.chart.height);
//draw a vertical line separating the two datasets, then draw a line 
connecting them
       ctx.save();
       ctx.beginPath();
       ctx.moveTo(chartFirstPointX, yBottom);
       ctx.lineTo(chartFirstPointX, yTop);
       ctx.moveTo(chartFirstPointX, lastActualY);
       ctx.lineTo(predictionFirstPointX, predictionFirstPointY);
       ctx.lineWidth = 2;
       ctx.strokeStyle = '#68D1FE';
       ctx.stroke();
       ctx.restore();
```